# Relations between @Entity in Spring application with microservices and one database

Tags: spring, relational-database, entity, microservices, entity-relationship

I'm creating `Spring` application with 2 microservices (at start, to extend later) and **ONE database**.

In first microservice, let's call it `BoardService` I have `@Entity` class `Board`.
In second microservice, let's call it `MessageService` I have `@Entity` class `Message`.

I want to create relation `Board - @OneToMany - Message`. One `Board` can have multiple `Message`s attached. Problem is that both entities are in separate packages, used in separated microservices.

When I start `MessageService` i get error:

`@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on my.package.messages.model.Message.board references an unknown entity: my.package.board.model.Carrier`

Here's how these classes look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boards")
class Board(
  @Id
  val id: Int,

  val name: String,

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Message::class, mappedBy = "board", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
  var messages: Set<Message>? = null
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
class Message(
  val name: String,

  val content: String,

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Board::class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "board_id")
  val board: Board? = null,

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  val id: Long? = null
)
```

I tried to add `Board` entity to second microservice using `EntityScan` but error remains the same.

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = [Board::class])
@Import(WebMvcConfig::class, WebSecurityConfig::class)
@SpringBootApplication
class MessagesMain
```

Is it even good approach to create relations between entities in different microservices?

If not, how should I proceed to assign `Message` to `Board`? Should I save in `messages` table `board_id`? But then if I get list of messages in `BoardService` (for example I want to show to client list of boards with messages attached to them) I would have to manually load from database `Board` object to each `board_id` in returned messages list from `MessageService`. It looks really inconvenient, especially when I'm using relational database.

I tried to find the right approach but I'm really confused by all posts and articles I have already read.

Comment: You cannot and should not. DOn't share code between microservics. They are seperate servics (and should preferably also have their own database(schema)).

Comment: @M.Deinum ok so how to assign ```Message``` to ```Board``` in this case?

Comment: That is too broad to answer. There are different options, depending on what you want. Also do you really need this to be different services as it doesn't look like that.

Comment: @M.Deinum it is a part of larger application in the future and I'd like to divide it into smaller microservices, where each is responsible for their own part. For sure at start as I said I would need in first microservice to get list of messages from second microservice and return it to client WITH assigned boards. I could iterate over list and assign to each ```Board``` object but it would have to be done manually

Comment: Microservices doesn't mean EACH entity needs its own service. Looks like these things belong together.

Comment: @M.Deinum in my app half of entities (30-40) will be connected somehow with ```Board``` so all 20-30 ```@Service``` classes that operate on them should be in one microservice?